# Compare same DataTable by certain columns, return mismatches to CopyToDataTable()

Tags: c#, linq

I have two DataTables (Columns: ID, MODEL, POWER, CLASS):

Table 1:

```
411 Audi   500 300
412 BMW    400 800
413 Lexus  200 700
```

Table 2:

```
876 Audi   500 300
896 BMW    400 870
832 Lexus  200 700
874 Fiat   250 450
```

As result I need to get (mismatch by at least one criteria, not taking in consideration ID):

```
412 BMW    400 800
896 BMW    400 870
```

I can't perform `Except` because there is first number that does not match between two (4.. & 8..). If I am querying before merging two DataTables together:

```
var matched = from table1 in MainProcess.dt1.AsEnumerable()
     join table2 in MainProcess.dt2.AsEnumerable()
     on table1.Field<string>("MODEL") equals table2.Field<string>("MODEL")

     where table1.Field<string>("POWER") != table2.Field<string>("POWER")
     || table1.Field<string>("CLASS") != table2.Field<string>("CLASS")
                 select table1;

     return matched.CopyToDataTable();
```

As result I am getting only one of results `412 BMW    400 800`. I have tried with `.Count() > 1 && .Count() < 1` but it didn't work either.

What is the right way to solve this problem? I guess I need to merge two DataTables before querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close:

```
var matched = from table1 in MainProcess.dt1.AsEnumerable()
    join table2 in MainProcess.dt2.AsEnumerable()
       on table1.Field<string>("MODEL") equals table2.Field<string>("MODEL")
    where table1.Field<string>("POWER") != table2.Field<string>("POWER")
        || table1.Field<string>("CLASS") != table2.Field<string>("CLASS")
    select new { table1, table2 };

var result = matched.SelectMany(x => new[] { x.table1, x.table2 })
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I was even closer trying this part as well `select new { table1, table2 };`, but was not able to figure the rest...